# .findall() giving everything after applying where condition in model

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js

I have three models Books,Author and Editor
Relation are as follows

```
Books.hasMany(Author);
Author.belongsTo(Editor);
```

I am getting all books even if Author is not matched.
Below I tried so far

```
Attributes.push('Id','Name') 
Books.findAll({
            
            include: [
                {model: Author, where:{Author:'XYZ'} ,attributes:, separate: true}
                , {model: Editor}
            ]
            , where:{ book_publication:'ABC' }
            
        });
```

I am getting below output. but book `Id=2` is not expected to be print because there is no author `XYZ` is present.

```
{
  "data": {
    "Books": [
      {
        "Id": 1,
        "Path": "/home/ubuntu/book1.pdf",
        "Name":"book1.pdf"
        "DateProposed": "2021-04-30 09:44:38",
        "book_publication":"ABC"
        "Author": [
          {
            "Id": 1,
            "Author":"XYZ"
            "Size": 10,
          }
        ],
        "Editor":{
           "Name":"PQRS"
}
      },
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "Path": "/home/ubuntu/book2.pdf",
        "DateProposed": "2021-04-07 12:22:36",
        "book_publication":"ABC"
        "Author": [],
        "Editor": {
          "Name": "PQRS"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add required flag at Editor model.

```
{model: Editor, required: true },
```